# I cannot get the second line (else if with less than 60) to output at all

Tags: if-statement, output

I've; changed the operator from < to <=, changed the statement from 'else if' to 'if' and nothing will get it to output. I'm a very new prgrammer with only a few weeks of class under my belt and could really use some help on what I'm missing here. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide. I've provided the instructions and my code.

**************Instructions************
Extend the template code to analyze a student's test score and give them advice, as follows:

(1) Add code to read a test score into the score variable.

Then evaluate the score entered, and use a decision statement to display some output.
When the score entered is 80 or above, output:
Doing well
Otherwise, output:
Study more
End your output with a newline.

(2) Extend the program to add one more check.

When the score entered is below 60, output:
and go to office hours for help
on the next line, ending again with a newline.

***********************MY CODE**************************************************************

```
// Author: Chelsie McFall

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScoreInterpreter {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);   
      int score = 0;
      
      System.out.println("Enter your test score:");
      score = scnr.nextInt();
    
      if (score >= 80) {                           
          System.out.println("Doing well");
      }

      if (score < 80) {        
          System.out.println("Study more");
      }
      else if (score < 60) {                        
          System.out.println("and go to office hours for help"); 
         
      }
   }
}
```

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esYp5.png)

Comment: Your `else if` does execute just as expected if you enter score less than 60

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. So, I did get each line to execute individually but I now can't get line 2/3 to outprint together as pic below shows (being 59 falls in both catgories). I've updated my code and attached a pic of expected output above. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've written it, the program will print either "Study more" *or* "and go to office hours for help".

The better way to code it would be:

```
if (score < 80) {        
    System.out.println("Study more");
}

if (score < 60) {                        
    System.out.println("and go to office hours for help"); 
}
```

This way, if the score is < 80 then it will print "Study more", and if the score is also < 60 then it will print "and go to office hours for help".

If you want to use an `else`, you could do it this way:

```
if (score >= 80) {                           
    System.out.println("Doing well");
} else {
    /* If we've gotten here, we know the score is < 80 */

    System.out.println("Study more");

    if (score < 60) {                        
        System.out.println("and go to office hours for help"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I was completely over-thinking this!

Answer (score 0):

Your code in 'elseif' will not be executed because you already have a condition in 'if' statement that satisfy for all values below 80. You can try following

```
if ($score <=80 && $score >= 60) {
// Do something
} elseif($Score < 60 ) {
// Do something
}
```